# "Unable to decode" Error with Jawbone OAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0, jawbone

I got the following error at the second step of Jawbone's OAuth flow (obtaining an access token via server-to-server POST request)

`{
  "error_description": "Unable to decode: 4/wCoR7RluPGtaJQXhhQToPoH9TqXHRzMBNpFj1mbWTxo",
  "error": "invalid_request"
}`

I tried to get the authentication code with different scopes and redirect URI's but everytime I post the code to Jawbone's token endpoint I get this error.

I tried to use cURL and Postman too, no difference here.

Do I miss something?

UPDATE: 
I found out, that it works with http/https based redirect URI's but I have to use a custom URL scheme like fitisfit://jawboneauth as my app needs to open after the user acceppts the permissions.

Comment: The Jawbone OAuth flow works with custom URL schemes. Could you provide the request that gives you the error?

Comment: I found the issue. It was kind of hard to debug.
The function that extract's the authentication code from the URI just cutted off the last character from the authentication code, so yeah, Jawbone didn't know that code.

Stupid error.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!